# Is it better to declare a function static to make it private or declaring it only on the .c file and excluding it from the header?

Tags: c, static-functions

I'm writing a library in c and there are some functions I would like to be callable from other c file and some I would like to keep private.

I know that it is possible to hide functions outside of the library file by declaring it `static` but the same can be achieved by declaring only the implementation on it and leaving it out from the header.

Compare:

```
a.h

//static int private_routine();
int sample();


a.c

/*static*/ int private_routine(){

}
int sample(){
  private_routine();
}
```

Which practice is best?

Comment: If the function is internal - keep it internal.

Comment: If it's not static, it's still emitted into the object, and can conflict with objects of the same name.

Comment: Declaring `static` symbols in a header is pointless. It has no benefits and can only cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep functions "private", or better, in scope of a single file, you need to declare them `static`. Otherwise you can redeclare the same function in other file and still use it.

For example:

```
#include "a.h" // without declaration of private_routine()

/*extern*/ int private_routine(); // by default every declaration behaves as with extern keyword, which means function is defined elsewhere

int main()
{
    private_routine(); // can use here
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: And as pointed in comments, it's not possible to define function with same name multiple times in one application without declaring it `static`.  If you define a given function name N times, at least N-1 of those must be `static`.

Comment: `extern` is a red herring here: *all* function declarations (which aren’t definitions) are `extern`, by definition. You only need to mark variable declarations `extern` explicitly.

Comment: Even worse, if multiple modules define an "internal" `private_routine` without declaring it `static`, linking will fail.

Comment: @melpomene Unless they declare it `inline`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - not so.   A `inline` definition may only be visible in the translation unit, but its identifier (e.g. the function name) still has external linkage if it is not also `static`.

Comment: @Peter That’s true but I was responding to the “linkage will fail” comment. And linkage *won’t* fail in this case (assuming the function is indeed the same one, otherwise the behaviour is UB).

Comment: On the contrary, @KonradRudolph, linkage might indeed fail.  This happens in the real world with some code and compilers.  If there is a function identifier declared with external linkage, and that function is called, then the Standard says there must be exactly one external definition of that function in the program.  `inline` definitions do not provide that.  Some compilers may choose to ignore the issue if they can direct each call to the function to an `inline` definition, but code that relies on that is non-conforming.

Comment: @Peter … just to add, yes, that function won’t be “internal” but users might assume it was, and I understood melpomene’s use of “internal-with-scare-quotes” to be not literal.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I’m not sure I follow. If I understand your comment correctly then inline definitions provide exactly that. Of course `inline` isn’t actually required to ensure that there’s really only a single definition. I’m not claiming that using `inline` magically fixes misuse. I’m claiming that there are valid situations where melpomene’s comment is strictly incorrect. Namely, that we can validly define `inline` functions in multiple TUs (as long as they refer to the same definition) without declaring them `static`.

Comment: No, @KonradRudolph, inline definitions *do not* provide that.  They are explicitly not external definitions (and that must be so, else there could not be more than one for any given identifier).  Note that this is a separate question from whether the function identifier has external linkage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I’m not claiming that they are external definitions. I’m claiming that two TUs having the following definition: `/* NO static */ inline void foo() {…}` can be valid.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean by "inline definitions provide exactly that," @KonradRudolph.  Let me be more clear about what *I'm* saying: attempting to make (used,) non-`static` functions private by declaring them `inline` is non-conforming and invites linkage errors unless there is an external (thus non-inline) definition of that function somewhere in the program, too.  But the OP's objective is to avoid that very situation, so no, making the function `inline` without also making it `static` is not a conforming solution. melpomene is right, at least in this context.

Comment: @JohnBollinger We agree. I disregarded the context because I read melpomene’s comment as a more general claim. In context, the comment is correct.